# Swift iOS 12 Beta UNUserNotification not firing

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to schedule a local iOS notification, but none pop up. I've verified 100% that the `adjustedDate` variable is valid, and I've confirmed that the notification trigger has the right date, through its `nextTriggerDate` function.

I've also verified that `UNUserNotificationCenter` requests notification permissions in `AppDelegate` and that works fine.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Test"
content.body = "More testing"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: Calendar.normalizedCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .calendar], from: adjustedTime), repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {
    error in

    if error != nil {
        self.out("Failed to add notification: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
    }
}
```